# How can I let others see events on my published calendar as not just "busy"?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

I created a Google calendar to embed on my website. I went to "Share this Calendar" and checked the following:

1. Share this calendar with others
2. Share this calendar with everyone my the organization

I then copied and pasted the embed code onto my website.

```
<p><iframe src="http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=hauscr.org_amh863cnb4564g11toarp9tfg8%40group.calendar.google.com&#038;ctz=America/New_York&#038;dates=20120201%2F20120315" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>
```

For 2., I selected "See all event details." Indeed, now, anyone logged in through my organization's Google apps can see my event details.

However, I also want the public set to "See all event details." Right now, all events are labeled to the public as merely "busy." The public cannot see the details of the events.

The option "1. Share this calendar with others" on the Google calendar interface does not let me select "See all event details." for the public.

Here is what I mean: Google Calendar will not let me reveal event details to the public; it's not an option in the select box.:
[image: Here is what I mean: Google Calendar will not let me reveal event details to the public; it's not an option in the select box.]
Does anyone know why? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure this is a good place for this question here. Perhaps it should be migrated to [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must allow users to reveal all details to outsiders of the domain. This is an administrator settings in the control panel of GAPPS.

Comment: Thanks, but when I set these settings (http://bit.ly/w0Yq5l) on the administrative control panel of Google apps (I am the admin.), the issue still persists. Google Calendar still does not let me select "Reveal all details." to the public. I have tried logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I believe my above error stemmed from browser caching.